# Using SwiftUI $ Xcode for macOS how do I get the position of the mouse in image coordinates when the mouse is over a CGImage?

Tags: xcode, macos, image, swiftui, mouseevent

I'm displaying grayscale images on my ContentView which have been scaled to UInt8 and would like to get the mouse location relative to the image origin when the mouse is hovering over the image. (I plan to use the to obtain and display the value in the original UInt16 data).

I'm detecting other mouse positions to change the cursor, etc. but can't find any solutions by searching.

Here is lightly edited code:

```
struct CGImageView: View {
    @Binding var filename: String?
    @Binding var minMax: [UInt16]

    @State private var opacity = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
            // probably should move this elswhere
        let data = importAndScaleImageData(filename!)
        let grayCGImageRef = createCGImageFromUint8(data, height: 240, width: 320)
        
        HStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Image(decorative: grayCGImageRef, scale: 1.0)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .border(Color.white)
            }
            .frame(width: CGFloat(grayCGImageRef.width), height: CGFloat(grayCGImageRef.height))
            .onHover { (hover: Bool) in
                if hover {
                    NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                } else {
                    NSCursor.pop()
                }
            }
            .onContinuousHover { 
                // *** get mouse location

            }
            .padding(10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For it to be at all performant, you'll want to move the "work" out of the `body` as the comment suggests -- otherwise that'll happen on every render pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the mouse position you could try this approach, as shown in this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "house")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 222, height: 222)
                .border(.red)
                .onHover { hover in
                    if hover {
                        NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                    } else {
                        NSCursor.pop()
                    }
                }
                .onContinuousHover { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .active(let location):
                        print("---> location: \(location)")
                    case .ended:
                        break
                    }
                }
        }.frame(width: 444, height: 444)
    }
}
```

Note, the upper-left corner of the image is location (0,0), you may have to do some coordinates transform to get what you want.

Comment: It's taken a long time but I now think that the image origin is at upper left ...  I'm really new at Xcode, Swift and SwiftUI so this has been a good learning experience.